# Can do-while loops only run with boolean variables? Java

Tags: java, boolean, do-while

I am having some trouble with this small segment. Can do-while loops only run using boolean variables? I am trying to ask the "user" to enter "0" or "1" so that the program will either loop or end.

Error message:

> Chapter4Practice.java:23: error: incompatible types: int cannot be
>   converted to boolean
>         } while (choice = 1);
>                         ^ 1 error

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter4Practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int choice, num1, num2;
        String input;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: "); 
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The sum is " + (num1 + num2));
            System.out.println("Do you want to do this again?");
            System.out.println("(1 = yes, 0 = no)");
            sc.nextLine();
            choice = sc.nextInt();
        } while (choice = 1);
    } //End Main

} //End Class
```

Comment: `choice = 1` **assigns** 1 to `choice`, and results in `1`, an `int`. `while(expr)` expects a `boolean` for `expr`. You surely meant to use `while(choice == 1)`

Comment: How silly of me! You are correct. I simply neglected to add another "=" sign. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can have simple or complex statements inside your do-while but at the end it will have to evaluate to either true or false

Also your statement should be == ( single = means assign, where == is evaluate)